# Passing large data in segue - Swift

Tags: swift

I have a view that tracks a user as they walk using location. This tracking generates a large amount of coordinates (5,000+). I then have a button that takes the user to another view which then plots those coordinates on a map as polylines (think fitness apps).

I have an issue where if the amount of data is large, once the user presses the button, the app freezes for a couple of seconds before going to the next view. This time gets longer the more data there is.

At the moment I am just appending each coordinate to an array and passing the entire array from one view to the next in prepareForSegue. I need to show another view as I have a lot of other controls on the second view.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to show the view instantly and then retrieve the data once loaded or a better method of storing the coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create variable with the coordinates in the AppDelegate, keep a single copy of the data there and access it from both view controllers. Each view controller can access AppDelegate easily:

```
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
} ()
```

If you created a `trackpoints` variable in the AppDelegate, you would access it as `appDelegate.trackpoints`.

This would address the data, but I suspect that the time is spent in the polyline/map part. You may want to consider creating the polyline and visible map region calculation asynchronously, so that the controller stays responsive and draws the track when it is ready.

Comment: Sounds great. Didn't think about storing the data in appDelegate. I have loaded URL asyn before but never ran a function. Will do some searching. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't consider every datapoint when drawing. Apple has a talk (WWDC 2015) about that but I can't find it ... In their sample fitness app they had the same problem. Since you can't draw 5000 data points they didn't draw them all, they filtered the array before.

Comment: Thanks. I was using snap to road in Google API and they only allow 100 points so I created a function that removed every n array items to reduce the size to this amount. Maybe I could do the same here but have the app draw maybe 1000 max. My only concern with that is if a user tracks their path for a very long time I would need to filter live and may result in odd paths. I am also only adding locations if they currently don't exist in the array. Given me something else to consider. Thanks.